# Cannot delete or restore files from Trash

Tags: trash, rm

When I try to delete a file from Trash I get the message Error while deleting There was an error getting information about "file.txt". Timeout was reached

If I remove the file using the `rm` command there is no message but the file is not deleted.

Comment: What is the exit code of `rm`? Enter `rm file.txt` and `echo $?` in the next command prompt. If it is 0 your file should be gone and not even be moved to trash.

Comment: Yes, it's 0, I removed the largest files (> 50 GB) this way and no longer get the time out error message.

Answer (score 0):

So, to have an answer to this question:

Delete the files with the `rm file.txt` command. Be aware that files deleted this way won't end up in the trash and can't be restored.

When `rm` exits with code `0` the file should be gone.